# Find the smallest positive number p that satisfies the condition

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It was a problem that took place on college entrance exam.

> Find the smallest positive number *p* for which the product of $$\boldsymbol p*(2\sqrt3-3\sqrt2)$$ is a whole number (integer).

Is there a general formula for solving this type of problem?

Comment: Yes: $a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog that was my goto when I tried solving it, but it doesn't produce the smallest possible number.

Comment: Can you do better than the reciprocal?

Comment: @lulu The number is negative, so its reciprocal doesn't work.

Comment: @eyeballfrog So take the negative of the reciprocal. Any other positive number, yielding an integer smaller than $-1$ has to be larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $p \ne 0$, the smallest choice of $p$ will have $|p(2\sqrt{3}-3\sqrt{2})| = 1$. Since $2\sqrt{3}-3\sqrt{2} < 0$ and $p >0$, that product must be $-1$. So we have
$$
p = \frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}-2\sqrt{3}}.
$$
Alternatively, we can use difference of squares to find
$$
(2\sqrt{3}+3\sqrt{2})(2\sqrt{3}-3\sqrt{2}) = 12-18 = -6.
$$
Divide both sides by $6$ to get
$$
\left(\frac{2\sqrt{3}+3\sqrt{2}}{6}\right)(2\sqrt{3}-3\sqrt{2}) = -1\Longrightarrow p = \frac{2\sqrt{3}+3\sqrt{2}}{6}.
$$
Despite the difference in form, these two values for $p$ are equal.

Comment: Thank you, that was the exact correct solution given by the exam organization.